# Delphi 10.3 Firedac SQLite Driver does not recognize SQLITE "Window functions"?

Tags: sqlite, aggregate, firedac

I refer to those aggregate functions with "OVER" clause. Delphi throws a syntax error message.
I tried to replace the sqlite3.dll in Delphi BIN folder. Did not help.
Appreciate any advice.
Thanks,

Comment: Probably using an old version of sqlite. You need 3.25 or newer for window functions.

Comment: Thanks. 
I already did that. I replaced sqlite3.dll in Delphi BIN folder with the latest one (ver 3.31). I also replaced it with the sqlite3.dll that comes with "Sqlite Expert Professional" where such SQL sentences work fine. Of course, I recompiled. Still I get the same error.

Comment: Found the Solution !!!
apparently you have to tell Delphi to link the SQLite library dynamically, but that is not enough. You have to compile some of its units (debug and release), and overwrite the originals.
Found the instructions here, and it works. The downside is that you need to have the sqlite3.dll in the app folder, or in the path

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55894657/delphi-firedac-not-recognizing-new-alter-feature-in-sqlite3

Comment: Dynamic linking is described in manual.