# Delphi FireDAC error when loading SQLite3.dll

Tags: sqlite, delphi, firedac, delphi-10-seattle

I already downloaded the latest SQLite.dll from [SQLite Download Page](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html) and try to load it using [TFDPhysDriverLink.VendorLib](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/fr/FireDAC.Phys.TFDPhysDriverLink.VendorLib)

But when I run the app, which contains the following code:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FDConnection1.Close;
  FDPhysSQLiteDriverLink1.Release;
  FDPhysSQLiteDriverLink1.VendorLib:= 'Path\SQLite3.dll';
  FDQuery1.Open('SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER() Col FROM TableName');
end;
```

It throws:

> [FireDAC][Phys][SQLite] ERROR: near "(": syntax error

Which means that the window function `ROW_NUMBER()` is not recognized.

- What I'm doing wrong?
- How can I force FireDAC to use the latest SQLite.dll?

Comment: Did you check the documentation to see if SQLite supports that syntax at all? And if it does, I believe that it's `OVER()` that is causing the issue.

Comment: `SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER() Col FROM TableName` is not valid SQL for sure.

Comment: How about `SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Col) FROM TableName`? See [Built-in Window Functions](https://sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html#built_in_window_functions).

Comment: Nope, `SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER() Col FROM TableName` is valid SQL @ArnaudBouchez, and even `SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY ColumnName) Col FROM TableName` is not working

Comment: What is the SQLite version? `SELECT sqlite_version()`

Comment: @PeterWolf FireDAC will returns `3.8.7.4` and that's why I'm trying to load the `SQLite.dll`

Comment: After setting up the physical driver link open the connection in the IDE  to the **Info** tab and see what it is loading and why. In the IDE it needs the 32bit version.

Comment: The IDE will load the statically linked .dll file @Brian `DLL = <sqlite3_x86.obj statically linked>`

Comment: Did you specify an absolute path?

Comment: Yup @Olivier I did

Comment: @moskito-x You really ask such question? The `TFDConnection.Connected` property will be `True` automatically when you call `TFDQuery.Open()` method. Sorry, but that is not related to the question.

Comment: just try : `FDPhysSQLiteDriverLink1.VendorLib:= 'Path\SQLite3.dll'; FDConnection1.Open; ..... `

Comment: It seem you have to recompile FireDAC, which is really lame. See answer to [Firedac not recognizing new ALTER feature in sqlite3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57192897/11562188).

Comment: It's simpler with [Sydney](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Connect_to_SQLite_database_(FireDAC)): no need to change FireDAC.inc anymore.

Comment: The trick didn't work too @PeterWolf

Comment: Did you put the DLL next to the executable, as mentioned in the [doc](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Connect_to_SQLite_database_(FireDAC))? Don't use `VendorLib`.

Comment: Also consider using [this alternative library](https://github.com/plashenkov/SQLite3-Delphi-FPC).

Comment: I don't see how `OVER()`  could be a valid syntax, from https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html point of view. You need some expression within OVER.

Comment: Read the docs again @ArnaudBouchez and especially the examples provided. `OVER` and `OVER()` are valid.

Comment: So perhaps FireDAC is validating the SQL before executing it, and doesn't know about Windowed functions. There are alternatives libraries with direct access to SQLite3.

Comment: The problem is that FireDAC keep using the [static licking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64336237/delphi-firedac-error-when-loading-sqlite3-dll?noredirect=1#comment113773911_64336237) @ArnaudBouchez

Answer (score 1):

SQLite do not support ROW_NUMBER.
Look at the answers for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50332436/syntax-error-when-using-row-number-in-sqlite3), you'll probably find something to replace ROW_NUMBER.

Comment: That statement is wrong. SQLite *supports* `ROW_NUMBER` since version [3.25.0](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_25_0.html). This is also what the most voted answer to the question you linked to says.

Comment: Read the docs https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_25_0.html

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error, then the `SQlite3.dll` was loaded just fine.

Just use the `RowID` field, which is always existing for any standard SQLite3 table - unless you explicitly created them with [CREATE TABLE WITHOUT ROWID](https://sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html) statement.

So I would just write:

```
 FDQuery1.Open('SELECT *, RowID FROM TableName');
```

Note that if there is an explicit `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` column in your table, it will in fact map the internal `RowID` column. Check [the SQLite3 documentation](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid) for how this works.

Comment: No, I don't want to use the `ROWID`, instead I want to use the window function. `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()` is just an example of window functions.